# Expanded Widget with child Chart issue

Tags: flutter

I'm trying to put a chart in a Column, but it shows me an error:

```
RenderFlex children have non-zero flex but incoming height constraints are unbounded.
```

Here the code:

[image]

Any help, please?

Answer (score 0):

In column widget, Expanded takes infinite width. Maybe it is affected the chart control while widget rendering. Can you wrap your chart inside the container and provide width and height for it and try?